# Vertical Table displaying a star relevant to the size of each int

Tags: c++, arrays, row, multiple-columns

I am writing a program for my c++ course where I need to display a vertical table that holds a length depending on each array size. The array size changes every run since it is 100 randomly generated numbers categorized under five different ints.

Here are my ints:

```
        int sizeA=0, sizeB=0, sizeC=0, sizeD=0, sizeF=0, arraySize=100, 
biggest=0, aB=0, cD=0;
        int grades[arraySize];
        std::vector<int> gradeA, gradeB, gradeC, gradeD, gradeF;
```

In my code, I took the 100 random numbers and sorted them into 5 new arrays using vectors; respectfully categorized as gradeA, gradeB, .. grade F;

I then used .size(); to get the size of each array and then found the biggest array size to use as my int biggest to declare the size of my table. Which is where I am stuck. I can't figure out how to display the columns and/or tables properly.

```
for(int row = biggest; row > 0; row--){
    for(int column = 0; column < 6; column++){
        cout << row << " ";
        if()
    } cout << endl;
}
```

My tables gotta look something like this, assuming sizeA = 3, sizeb=2, 3, 1, 2 respectfully:

```
3 *   *
2 * * *   *
1 * * * * * 
  A B C D F
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: I don't get what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What don't you get

Comment: Even with an answer that  you've selected as solution, I don't see what you're trying to achieve or what the problem is, it's bafflingly unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(gradeA.size() >= row)
   cout<<"* "; // One space at the end to separate from next star
else
   cout<<"  "; // Two spaces here to keep aligned your table
```

same with gradeB, gradeC...

EDIT: The columns loop then can be removed

```
for(int row = biggest; row > 0; row--)
{
    cout << row << " ";
    if(gradeA.size() >= row)
        cout<<"* "; // One space at the end to separate from next star
    else
        cout<<"  "; // Two spaces here to keep aligned your table
    if(gradeB.size() >= row)
        cout<<"* "; // One space at the end to separate from next star
    else
        cout<<"  "; // Two spaces here to keep aligned your table
    // Same for gradeC, D, E and F
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it causes replicas as seen in this pastebin. https://pastebin.com/vwpa85bZ

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstood what you had on those vectors. I thought that once filled you only cared about the size to show the stars in the output. Not sure about what "replicas" mean, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, originally I needed the values of each array, but I guess I just need to graph how many are in the actual category of A grade or B grade.. etc. Which is what the graph is trying to show, how many are in each category.

Comment: See the edited answer. Maybe it makes more sense now, with the if integrated in the loop.